# Textarea background image scrolling when entering more text in ie8

Tags: css, internet-explorer-8, background, textarea

Textarea background image scrolling when entering more text in ie8, i have used sprite concept in css so when entered text more its showing another image as background

```
textarea{
  border:0 none; 
  background:url(../images/sprite.png) no-repeat -272px -63px; 
  max-height:80px; 
  max-width:191px; 
  overflow-y: auto;
}
```

Comment: This doesn't happen in IE8 if your page is being displayed in IE8 mode. It *is happening* for you, which means your page is being displayed in IE7 mode, or quirks mode (to check, hit F12 to bring up the Developer Tools). Fix that problem, and your problem will fix itself. Of course, if you need to support genuine IE7, you'll still need a fix like the one in your answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since Microsoft “corrected” the background attachment issues with IE7 and now is no way of having an overflow of text in a input or textarea element and not having the background scroll with the text, and if you try “background-attachment: fixed;” the background doesn’t even display. Because is no really css hack what fix the problem, you need to think out of css. Instead to style just the textarea element, make a supplementary div like container for textarea and apply the background image to the div, instead to textarea. Let the textarea without border and background to make a proper overlay. so i am using code like this

```
.textarea_div{background:url(../images/sprite.png) no-repeat -272px -63px;}
textarea{border:0 none; 
max-height:80px; 
min-height:80px; 
max-width:191px; 
min-width:191px;}
```

HTML

```
<div class="textarea"><textarea></textarea></div>
```

Comment: I got this information from http://www.readactor.com/fix-ie7-scrolling-background-problem-in-textarea-form-fields/

Answer (score 0):

Use this:

```
background:fixed url(../images/sprite.png) no-repeat -272px -63px;
```

Comment: Sorry if we use this, background doesn’t even display. Try if u want know

Comment: That's gonna be difficult with just the code you provided... But what do you mean by 'if we use *this* background'?

Comment: That's mean if we use background-attachment:fixed; doesn’t even display background, and thanq for your replay..

Comment: I found a page concerning using multiple background images, check it out (see the title 'multiple background images' for the example) http://www.w3schools.com/css3/css3_backgrounds.asp

Comment: @ poepje thanq for your suggestion but it wont work for ie8 or lower versions. See my answer above.

Comment: Ok, too bad, I'm afraid I don't know it either then. Good luck with it ;)

Answer (score 0):

Sorry in advance if i misunderstood you question.

Do you need this, see Demo in IE8 by clicking the following URL:

http://jsfiddle.net/rathoreahsan/MmVwA/4/